# Relations created with YAML in Symfony (with Doctrine) are not populated in MySQL database

Tags: doctrine, yaml, symfony1

I am new to Symfony, trying to create a database structure through build-model then build-sql.

All the tables appear in the database however relations other than simple one-to-many relations are not created.

For instance I have a table storing companies, they can be both suppliers or customers and I have another table storing the customer/supplier relationship.

```
Identifier:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  tableName: identifier
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
  relations:
    Suppliers:
      class: Identifier
      local: customer_id
      foreign: supplier_id
      refClass: CustomerSupplier
      foreignAlias: Customers
      onDelete: CASCADE
    Customers:
      class: Identifier
      local: supplier_id
      foreign: customer_id
      refClass: CustomerSupplier
      foreignAlias: Suppliers
      onDelete: CASCADE
CustomerSupplier:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  tableName: customerSupplier
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    customer_id:
      type: integer(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    supplier_id:
      type: integer(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
```

One-to-one relationships are not created either:

```
IdentifierExtCompany:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  tableName: identifierExtCompany
  columns:
    identifier_id:
      type: integer(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
  relations:
    Identifier:
      local: identifier_id
      foreign: id
      onDelete: CASCADE
      foreignType: one
      type: one
```

All these relations don't appear in the database when I run the sql request generated by build-sql.

Could you help me to detect what is wrong in my yaml file? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using MyISAM? What exactly do you call "relations" in MySQL? foreign keys? N:M tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For instance I have a table storing companies, they can be both suppliers or customers and I have another table storing the customer/supplier relationship.

Seems like you have to define relations for `CustomerSupplier` too:

```
relations:
  IdentifierAlias:
    class: Identifier
    local: identifier_id
    onDelete: CASCADE
  SupplierAlias:
    class: Supplier
    local: supplier_id
    onDelete: CASCADE
```

> One-to-one relationships are not created either

Try to specify `class` attribute in relations and set it to `Identifier`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I found a workaround. No idea why, relations are not populated properly when I run `doctrine:build-model` followed by `doctrine:build-sql` and `doctrine:insert-sql`. It works just fine when I run `doctrine:build --all --no-confirmation`